# -2147483648 value in integer type column

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, int, overflow

> This Question may not be related But am badly stuck in it and found no way except to ask question over here.

I've `silverlight UserControl` having a **telerik** **textbox** field that is `RadMaskedNumericInput` with **#6** Mask value, means it could only have 6 digits. But when I examine my **DataBase**, some values of this field are like **-2147483648**.

I've tried to enter many values but `unable to reproduce` this scenario. I can only enter **6 digits** from screen and I tried max **999999** but it remains the same.

Is there anyone having idea why its happening?? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**(Updated)** I'm only getting textbox value, converting it to int and then insert it to Database through a Stored Procedure.

```
int value = (int)txtPrice.value;
```

> I've tried to enter a negative value as well as trying to add letters but
>   due to mask, its not allowing me to add any value other than integers.

Comment: Show your code. Try with `-` or letters.

Comment: see updated question. no specific code over there.

Comment: I've tried with - value but manually its not allowing me to enter - value due to mask

Comment: Does any other application has access to DB? Do you track who insert/update record?

Comment: I suggest putting logging into your application when an out of expected range value is found.

Comment: @lad2025 data can only be inserted through screen but its not allowing any -ve value

Comment: Does mask allow typing decimal point or `e` for scientific notation?

Comment: Check your database to see if there is a default constraint or trigger on that column.   If not, then post the stored procedure code.

Comment: @lad2025 no mask does not allow any decimal point or e for scientific notation.

Comment: @TabAlleman No there is no any default constraint or trigger on that column. 
`SP Code`
    `INSERT INTO TABLE(Column)`
    `VALUES(@value);`

Comment: Use profiler to see what value is being passed to the stored procedure from the application when it gives the unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

`-2147483648` is `int.MinValue`.

It seems that the `RadMaskedNumericInput` field doesn't have a minimum value set or the default value isn't set.

You can set the minimum value using the [MaskedInputExtensions](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radmaskedinput/features/extensions).

For example,
`<telerik:RadMaskedNumericInput Value="0" maskedInput:MaskedInputExtensions.Minimum="0" />`